# Change webpack generated external IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to change the IP address that Webpack is generating for my Dev environment.
Is that even possible?

I am using a Vue CLI with the standard settings, accept that I am Proxying to port 3000.

This is what it looks like in the console:

[image]

And I need to change the External: http://192.168.1.102:5000 to http://192.168.1.101:5000

Answer (score 0):

I might try  [browser-sync-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin). You can set up the proxy and the host which is the ip you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Browsersync, but in webpack you can modify the config to use `host`:

```
host: 192.168.1.101
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-host